# Error assembly junk at the end of line

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

english it's not my first language so if i spell wrong some words sorry. I'm new to Assembly language and actaully i'm learning from a book that explain assembly on linux. When i try to run this command on terminal:

```
as primo.s -o primo.o
```

It's give me this errors:

```
primo.s: Assembler messages:
primo.s:5: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character valued 0xffffffe2
primo.s:9: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
primo.s:12: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `push'
```

The code is this:

```
#  Primo Programma
#
.section .data
output_string:
.ascii “Pronti Via!!!\n\0”
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl $output_string  
call printf
addl $4,%esp
pushl $0
call exit
```

Comment: Wrong type of quotes is one major problem on this line `.ascii “Pronti Via!!!\n\0”` You should use the standard quote symbol `"`

Comment: Secondly I am guessing the `push` fails because you are likely on a 64-bit system generating 64-bit code by default. To get `as` to assemble and produce 32-bit objects on 64-bit Linux use `as --32 primo.s -o primo.o`